# jquery drag image to table and update database

Tags: jquery, mysql, drag-and-drop

I have a table with 4 images and an **N** number of 4x4 tables. What I have to do is to move those 4 images in those tables and update the database with what image has been added and on which position to use it later to post it back.

I don't know too much about what jquery and ajax can do; So I need to know if is possible to use only tables, or I need to use forms for that. And considering that I would have **N** tables I need an idea how to structure them in db (adding N columns doesn't sound right).
From what I searched so far I understand that is possible with jquery ui and ajax.
What I need is an idea and if is possible a starting point would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to save in database? As image or just image details like name?
You can look in Jquery Documentation
[Look for draggable here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

[For Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: I want to save the image name or id and the position where is in the table so I can put it back later